# PHP PDO check if a table with specific name exists in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following code checks for tables on the database.

```
function checkdbexists(){
    global $krdb;
    return $krdb->query("show tables");
}
```

We want to check whether a table called 'systems' exists returning 1 if it does and null or 0 if it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
array_search('system',$krb->query('show tables')->fetch())!==false;
```

Comment: Marvellous. Perfect accespted in 6 mins

Answer (score 1):

```
select 1
from information_schema.tables
where table_name = 'systems'
limit 1
```

Comment: ...or if you want to return 0 if it doesn't exist you can do `SELECT IF((SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'systems') = 1, 1, 0) AS exists`

Answer (score 1):

```
$db_tables = array_keys($pdo->query('show tables')->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_GROUP));

if(in_array('myTable', $db_tables)) 
{ 
    print "myTable exist"; 
}
```

Comment: Strangely enough all the other methods on this page did not work for me, but this one did